# dragAndDrop NOT working on Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, typescript, drag-and-drop, protractor

I am trying to perform a Drag and Drop operation on our Angular application using Protractor Jasmine. I am able to get hold of the source item but as the test runs, the source element gets selected but nothing happens thereafter; the drag and drop operation does not take place. There are no errors shown in the console.

An interesting thing about the destination container is that the items dropped here can be resized as per user wish. Also, there is no clearly marked place/area in the destination container where the dragged item will get dropped! But the container does have an ID; though that has still not helped here.

Here is the code:

```
let dragAndDrop = require('html-dnd').code;

.
.
.


function dragAndDropListItems(fdIndex: number): void {                                                 
    let dragElement = element.all(by.repeater('listDefinition in lists')).get(fdIndex); // Select the first repeater corresponding to the first List Item in the list

    let dragElementh5 = dragElement.all(by.css('a')).get(0); // Select the first List Item
    let printFD = dragElementh5.getText().then((text: string) => {
        console.log(text); // Print the innerHTML text from the chosen List Item to the Console
    });

    let finalDrop = element.all(by.css('[id="dashboardContainerDiv"]')).get(0);

    dragElement.click();
    browser.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, finalDrop).perform();

};
```

[image: souce and destination location]

[image: Manual DragAndDrop]

I have tried using coordinate based DragNDrop operation as well but the same in every case.

Other tried options include:

```
    //browser.executeScript(dragAndDrop, dragElement, finalDrop); // Perform the drag and drop operation 

    //browser.driver.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, finalDrop).perform();

    //browser.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, { x: 400, y: 400 }).perform();      
   // browser.driver.actions().mouseDown(dragElement).mouseMove(finalDrop).mouseUp(finalDrop).perform();
```

Kindly suggest a solution to this issue.

@FlorentB. I have attached the Code with your scripts imported.

let JS_DRAG_DROP  = require('./drag-drop.js');

function dragAndDropListItems(fdIndex: number): void {

```
/*
let source = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#drag")
target = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#drop")
driver.execute_async_script(JS_DRAG_DROP, source, target)

# drag and drop an element by offset {x:500, y:200}
source = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#drag")
driver.execute_async_script(JS_DRAG_DROP, source, None, 500, 200)

# drag and drop an element with a delay of 101ms before the drop
source = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#drag")
target = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#drop")
driver.execute_async_script(JS_DRAG_DROP, source, target, 0, 0, 101)
*/

 let source = element.all(by.repeater('listDefinition in 
 lists')).get(fdIndex); // Select the first repeater corresponding to the 
 first List Item in the list
let dragElementh5 = source.all(by.css('a')).get(0); // Select the first List 
Item
let printFD = dragElementh5.getText().then((text: string) => {
    console.log(text); // Print the innerHTML text from the chosen List Item 
    to the Console
});


//browser.driver.switchTo().frame('dashboardContainerDiv'); 

/*
let finalDropClass = element.all(by.css('[class="dashboard mb10"]')).get(0); 
let finalDropCon = 
finalDropClass.all(by.css('[id="dashboardContainerDiv"]')).get(0);
let finalDrop = 
finalDropCon.all(by.css('[id="dashboardContainerUl"]')).get(0);  
*/

let target  = element.all(by.css('[id="dashboardContainerDiv"]')).get(0);

//dragElement.click();

browser.executeScript(JS_DRAG_DROP, source, target); // Perform the drag and 
drop operation 
//browser.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, finalDrop).perform();

//browser.driver.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, finalDrop).perform();

//browser.actions().dragAndDrop(dragElement, { x: 400, y: 400 }).perform();
```

// browser.driver.actions().mouseDown(dragElement).mouseMove(finalDrop).mouseUp(finalDrop).perform();

};

Comment: @Thomas Rollet Thank you for the edit

Comment: The page implements an HTML5 drag and drop which is not supported by Selenium. You'll have to inject a script to emulate the events. See https://gist.github.com/florentbr/60ef7cb8d9b1ae690cafc82aad52da73

Comment: @FlorentB. Thank you for your suggestion. Are you referring to the 'aside' Tag here? I have got the 'aside' Tag removed and tried the dragNdrop (without added the scripts you suggested). It does not work.

Comment: @FlorentB. I have now also tried the dragNdrop operation using your scripts. I get the error message: "Source element is not draggable" as defined in your scripts. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Try

https://github.com/html-dnd/html-dnd

Installing it and using the typescript example worked for me.